# I've been using a function in Swift with a great Return Closure

Tags: python, swift

I've been using a Function is Swift that I am trying to emulate in Python 3.7.4. This is the Swift isPrime function:

```
func isPrime(_ number: Int) -> Bool {
return number > 1 && !(2..<number(.contains {number % $0 == 0}
```

I want a "1-liner" Return like the above but in Python 3.7.4

I've tried everything I know but without any success. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please update your question with some of your attempts in Python. Even the non-working ones.

Comment: I tried.  def isPrime(number) -> Bool :                                                               
return number > 1 and  not in range (2, number).contains { number % $0 == 0 }

Comment: That's good. Now can you update the question with that code?

Comment: I want a Python function return,    that works, this one doesn't....

Comment: How do you know it doesn't?

Comment: If you really want short code for it, you may want to ask the question at https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: because I've tried it and it generates endless errors...

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
import math

def isPrime(n):
  return n in [2,3] or (n >= 5 and all(n % i for i in ([2, 3] + list(range(3, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 2)))))
```

Here are some tests:

```
print (isPrime(0))  #False
print (isPrime(4))  #False
print (isPrime(8))  #False
print (isPrime(9))  #False
print (isPrime(33)) #False

print (isPrime(2))  #True
print (isPrime(3))  #True
print (isPrime(5))  #True
print (isPrime(11)) #True
print (isPrime(59)) #True
```

You could also use [the](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/six.html) property of prime numbers that they all can be written as `6 * x + 1` or `6 * x - 1`, with `x` being a positive integer, in order to make the function a bit more performant:

```
def isPrime(n):
  root = int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1
  return n in [2,3] or (n >= 5 and all(n % i for i in ([2, 3] + list(range(5, root, 6)) + list(range(7, root, 6)))))
```

---

Shorter (but less efficient) could be:

```
def isPrime(n): 
  return n>1 and not {i for i in range(2,n) if n%i==0}
```

Comment: That looks much better,  thanks. I'd just got used to building closures in Swift when I found Python. It's amazing and FUN too. I've built a lot of code with isPrime and it's time to slim it all down now. This helps, so thanks ielyamani.